# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: authorname):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a some trouble on my heroku-server. Not getting this problem locally:

```
2014-07-23T16:59:23.249055+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: authorname):
2014-07-23T16:59:23.249058+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/chapters_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

My controller:

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
        @chapter = @story.chapters.create(chapter_params)
        redirect_to story_path(@story)
    end

    def destroy
        @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
        @chapter = @story.chapters.find(params[:id])
        @chapter.destroy
        redirect_to story_path(@story)
    end

    def upvote
        @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
        @chapter.votes.create
        redirect_to(:back)
    end

    private
        def chapter_params
            params.require(:chapter).permit(:round, :author, :authorname, :body)
        end
end
```

I have just added authorname with

```
rails g migration add_authorname_to_chapter authorname:string
```

What am I missing?

Edit, adding schema info:
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140723154333) do

```
  create_table "chapters", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "round"
    t.string   "author"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "story_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "authorname"
  end
```

Comment: May be a silly question but you did use `rake db:migrate` after creating the migration right?

Comment: I am totally expecting it to be something silly :) But no, I ran rake db:migrate yes

Comment: @yarism another silly question but did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` or just rake db:migrate :)

Comment: Would you add the relevant schema information?

Comment: Kind of like @Mandeep suggested, since you are only getting the problem in production and not locally did you push the changes out to production?

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate on local server and heroku run rake db:migrate on heroku when I pushed it on there.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140723154333) do

  create_table "chapters", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "round"
    t.string   "author"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "story_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "authorname"
  end

Comment: Have you restarted your server since you did the migration?

Comment: can you also post your form for creating chapters?

Comment: No I haven't restarted and that seemed to fix the issue, thank you mcfinnigan! And thanks for all the other proposals!

Comment: @mcfinnigan - I think you should write your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @yarism install pry, and before create action, make sure that model Chapter has the authorname field.

Comment: which version of rails you are using?

Comment: rails 4.1.2, but the issue has already been fixed by @mcfinnigan proposal

Answer (score 6):

Restarting your server after migration will refresh the schema cache.

Answer (score 2):

For the case that a restart doesn't work I was able to resolve this issue by also dumping the schema:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:dump
heroku restart
```